# Swift 3 Changing Cell Shape and Attributes

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a small program printing "blocks" to the screen. I want block numbers 8 and 11 to be circles, but I'm having trouble figuring how how to reference them individually.

When this code runs (no matter how I set the for loop constraints) it will place as many blocks as there are in my items array.

I thought I could say something like while count < 8 .... and so on, but even if it just runs one time, it places however many items are in "items" to the screen. Regardless, I'd like to be able to have #8 and #11 be circles.

Thanks in advance

```
let reuseIdentifier = "cell"
var items = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18"]

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDataSource protocol

// tell the collection view how many cells to make
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.items.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell


    for _ in 0..<18 {
    let rnd1 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    let rnd2 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    let rnd3 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(rnd1), green: CGFloat(rnd2), blue: CGFloat(rnd3), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    }

    return cell
}

// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegate protocol

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // handle tap events
    count += 1
    counterLabel.text = "\(count)"
    print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")
}
```

[Here's what the code is producing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo8iT.png)

Comment: You shouldn't have a loop in cellForItemAtIndexPath`; this function will be called once for each cell;  check the `indexPath.item` value to determine which cell you are returning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a visually circular cell, you can set the cornerRadius of a UIView inside your cell to be equal to the width and height.
Also including idlehand comment, there is no need for you to loop the generation of a cell. You can try a code similar to:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    // get a reference to our storyboard cell
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell
    // Use the outlet in our custom class to get a reference to the UILabel in the cell

    let rnd1 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    let rnd2 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    let rnd3 = Double.random(min: 0.1, max: 1.0)
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(rnd1), green: CGFloat(rnd2), blue: CGFloat(rnd3), alpha: CGFloat(1.0))
    cell.myLabel.text = self.items[indexPath.item]

    if indexPath.item == 7 || indexPath.item == 10 {
        cell.myCustomBackground.layer.cornerRadius = cell.myCustomBackground.frame.width
    }

    return cell
}
```

Where myCustomBackground is a Square UIView that is centered in your cell.
Also with regards to your problem of identifying your cells, in a collection view the indexPath.item will give you its position in that section.